# configure C++11 properly on Netbeans 8.0.2 on mac

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans, netbeans-8

I had difficulty using C++11 compile via Netbeans.  I have added '-std=c++11' in the additional option and the Netbeans gave me the following error:

```
error: invalid value 'c++11' in '-std=c++11'
```

BTW I already have GCC 4.8.4, and C++11 works fine when I just use my terminal.
Any suggestions? Should I set path for the compiler somewhere? Thanks.

Update:

I set the path of g++ compiler to the proper one on Properties->Build, now I get another slightly different error message:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

Really need some help here! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your compiler is setup properly (**`Tools -> Options -> C/C++`**, use `Versions ...` to test if everything is ok).

You can enable C++11 by the project settings: Open the project options, go to  **`Build -> C++ Compiler`** and select **C++11** at the **`C++ Standard`** option.

If building fails, please check (and post) the build output. There should be some g++ lines, look for the `std=c++11` part there.

Comment: Is there a way to set this option globally? I don't want to change that setting every time I create a project. Could not find a solution yet unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately not, maybe with NB8.1 (coming into Beta soon). But it's a good idea to open an issue for this.

Comment: **Good news** - it's possible with **NB8.1** (Beta has been released today): In the **C/C++ settings** go to *Other* and there you can set the *default standard* for C and C++!